# Is there a reason the PHP `mail()` function would not send a message containing a link to the domain it's coming from?

Tags: php, email

I'm running the PHP `mail()` function and the email is simply not sent if the message contains mydomain.org, where mydomain.org is the domain the server is hosting.

Here's what I have:

```
$subject = 'hey there';
$message = 'you have been invited to mydomain.org/index.php?blah=776876';
mail('test@gmail.com', $subject, $message, 'From:admin@mydomain.org' . "\r\n");
```

If `$message` contains "mydomain.org", it will not send the email. If I change .org to .com, it works. If I remove the 'g' and make it .or, it works. Any url other than mydomain.org works.

I know I should be using an email client, but in the meantime, any help much appreciated.

Comment: is there an error from your server? does it get sent and then flagged as spam? what happens?

Comment: no, it's definitely not the URL. could it be the spam filter? did you check spam folder?

Comment: Definitely not the spam filter--it's just not showing up anywhere. I'm not getting any error message either.

Comment: It is working fine and I am able to send mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hosting provider is likely prevent sending emails with links to the host domain as an anti-spam tactic.  Odd that they let you link to other sites, but not your own, as I'd generally think links to remote sites would be more concerning, but nevertheless, I'm fairly certain that's what you're running into.

I would reach out to your provider's customer service and find out what you can do; since they allow you to send emails at all, they probably have some way to let you do this, perhaps as long as it's throttled to a certain number per minute, or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it may be what's going on. The weird thing is that it worked earlier today and has worked during our several months of testing. All of a sudden it's just stopped with no change to our code, like a switch was flipped.

Comment: Definitely sounds like some sort of threshold your script crossed, support ought to be able to help work it out with you.

Comment: Support wasn't able to do anything, so we're using a crazy workaround until we can figure something else out (using a link to send users to another of our sites and having that site redirect to mydomain.org). Thanks for the help @dimo.